# Python import pattern: directory name in a separate file pointing to root file

Tags: python, import, directory

I have encountered a pattern in a [public git repository](https://github.com/udacity/artificial-intelligence-for-trading)* hosted by Udacity that I can't find any documentation on:

The folder structure is:

```
|-- quiz
|     |-- m1 
|          |-- L2
|               |-- quiz_tests.py
|               |-- tests.py
|               |-- quiz notebook.ipynb
|-- tests.py
```

notebook.ipynb imports
`import quiz_tests` -> which imports `tests.py` -> which only contains the following:
`../../../tests.py` (with no quotation marks)

When I try to run this it gives me an import error:
`cannot import name 'project_test' from 'tests'`

What is this pattern and how can I make it work?

Thanks in advance!

**unfortunately [the issue](https://github.com/udacity/artificial-intelligence-for-trading/issues/9) asking about the same question got closed without answer*

Code:

notebook.ipynb

```
import quiz_tests

def calculate_returns(close):
    return None

quiz_tests.test_calculate_returns(calculate_returns)
```

quiz_tests.py

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from tests1 import project_test, generate_random_tickers, generate_random_dates, assert_output


@project_test
def test_calculate_returns(fn):
    tickers = generate_random_tickers(5)
    dates = generate_random_dates(6)

    fn_inputs = {
        'close': pd.DataFrame(
            [
                [21.050810483942833, 17.013843810658827, 10.984503755486879, 11.248093428369392, 12.961712733997235],
                [15.63570258751384, 14.69054309070934, 11.353027688995159, 475.74195118202061, 11.959640427803022],
               ],
            dates, tickers)}
    fn_correct_outputs = OrderedDict([
        (
            'returns',
            pd.DataFrame(
                [
                    [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                    [-0.25723988, -0.13655355, 0.03354944, 41.29534136, -0.07731018],
              
                dates, tickers))])

    assert_output(fn, fn_inputs, fn_correct_outputs)
```

tests.py

```
../../../tests.py
```

Comment: Please add your code snippet.

Comment: Done, I have added them!

Comment: You cannot just import a file that has an address to another file.
You must use `importlib` library for this purpose.
See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you think this is a mistake in the original github repo? Or do they have a different python runtime configured around it?

Comment: I think maybe this is a mistake in github repo 